# date regex which validates 3 different formats

Tags: regex

I need a regex for date string which validates

```
YYYY:MM:DD:HH   
YYYY:MM:DD:HH:mm    
YYYY:MM:DD:HH:mm:ss
```

means all 3 formats are valid.
Can someone help me with this ?

I have

- `d\d\d\d:(0\d|1[012]):([012]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3])$` YYYY:MM:DD:HH
- `^\d\d\d\d:(0\d|1[012]):([012]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$` YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM
- `^\d\d\d\d:(0\d|1[012]):([012]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$` YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS

These 3 regex and needs to be combine in one

Comment: Heh, if you want to take in account that `0<MM<13` and n days with leap years etc... This would be a tough mission, that's why don't try to validate dates with regex, you will fail.

Comment: @Lyuben at present i have 
d\d\d\d:(0\d|1[012]):([012]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3])$                       YYYY:MM:DD:HH
^\d\d\d\d:(0\d|1[012]):([012]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d$               YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM
^\d\d\d\d:(0\d|1[012]):([012]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$       YYYY:MM:DD:HH:MM:SS 
these 3 regex and needs to be combine in one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is your pattern

```
YYYY:MM:DD:HH(:mm(:ss)?)?
```

`?` means 0 or 1 time

you can test it [here](http://regexpal.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I kept your year month day expression `d\d\d\d:(0\d|1[012]):([012]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3])`. Since your hour and minute expressions where the same `:[0-5]\d` I just required them to appear zero, once or twice with.

The resulting expression is:

`^\d\d\d\d:(0\d|1[012]):([012]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}$`

[image]

This expression by [francis-gagnon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/870144/francis-gagnon) is a slight modification to prevent edge cases where the day or month is expressed as `00`.

`^\d\d\d\d:(0[1-9]|1[012]):(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}$`

[image]

If you're looking to also check the date is valid then you could use something like this monster which will test each date position to it's valid and that the time will fit into 24 hour clock:

`^(?:(?:(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)))(:|\/|-|\.)(?:0?2\1(?:29)))|(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})(:|\/|-|\.)(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])\2(?:31))|(?:(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2(?:29|30))|(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\2(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8]))))(?::(?:[01]\d|2[0-3]))?(?::[0-5]\d){0,2}$`

[image]

Comment: This is the best solution here, but you are missing a backslash on your first digit for the year. Also this regex accepts the following date: 2012:00:00:23:59:59.

Comment: Good catch on that missing slash. I wanted to use the requester's own regex as they had something that worked but they couldn't get all three expressions to work together. If I where to validate the a date in yyyy-mm-dd format I'd probably use something like the monster in the update.

Comment: I guess it depends on the requirements the OP has. Personally I think we'd be better off with something simpler (more like your original regex). This one fixes the issue for the 00 for the months and days: ^\d\d\d\d:(0[1-9]|1[012]):(0[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01]):([01]\d|2[0-3])(:[0-5]\d){0,2}$

Comment: Yep that'll prevent the `00` day or month edge case. I added it as an option.

Answer (score 0):

```
\d{4}:[0-1][0-9]:[0-3][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9](?::[0-5][0-9])?)?
```